# 'Invalid security token' on Joomla login

Tags: joomla, joomla3.3

I am getting the following error at the time of log in to my Joomla site. Though it is not showing this error all the time and i logged in successfully several times. What is the reason of this?

> The most recent request was denied because it contained an invalid security token. Please refresh the page and try again.

Answer (score 2):

This usually occurs because you've tried to log in after backing up to the login page, where a token has already been stored. You can usually resolve it with a hard refresh (shift-refresh) or by clearing cookies.

Comment: Isn't it CTRL+F5 for hard refresh ?

Comment: Yes it is, also. I find that shift-refresh is easier with my workflow.

Comment: None of these solutions are user friendly at all

Comment: I agree. It's a shame that it's still a problem years later.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused due to active session (not closed properly) in the Joomla! sessions table.

Follow below steps to resolve these errors:

1. Login to cPanel.
2. Access the DB using PhPmyAdmin.
3. Delete all the user sessions from the 'vnto1_session' table.

Now website is accessible without any errors.

Comment: How has no one up voted this yet? Clearly joomla is not handling their sessions properly, and this was the answer that led to the solution for me.

Answer (score -1):

I remove current web.config and rename/insert default web.config in joomla installation folder to installed joomla folder and check the php is correctly installed in IIS.